# How does scanf() works?

Tags: c++, c

I get confused with the following code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int num1, int num2;
        scanf("%d/%d", &num1, &num2);
        printf("%d", num2);
    }
```

when the input is just 12, why I get 32767?

Comment: probably because num2 is uninitialized if you wrote only 12. If I read it correctly it expects input of format a/b where `a` and `b` are both integers.

Comment: but why exactly 32767? And what sense does "/" make?

Comment: / is just part of the format.

Comment: thx, but I am still confused about the output, is it just some random number or sth going on there?

Comment: Because the input "12" does not match the format you promised `scanf` you were going to supply. Namely, an integer followed by a slash and then another integer.

Comment: @FrankTian: Yes.  It's a completely random number because the input was bad, and you ignored the return value of `scanf` where it told you the input was bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't *always* get a 32767, because `num2` remains uninitialized. Here is how you can tell if `num2` is or is not initialized:

```
int how_many = scanf("%d/%d", &num1, &num2);
if (how_many == 0) {
    printf("Nothing is entered\n");
} else if (how_many == 1) {
    printf("Only num1 is entered: %d\n", num1);
} else {
    printf("Both numbers are entered: %d and %d\n", num1, num2);
}
```

Comment: thx, but as num2 remains unintialized, then nothing is stored in num2, but how can the program still have output though?

Comment: @FrankTian it's called memory! That's why!

Comment: @FrankTian When a variable is uninitialized, it does not mean that it has no value at all: all it means that the value in that variable is arbitrary, because it has not been written there by your program. It happens that in your case the value of `32767` is stored in `num2` at the beginning of your run, so it remains there when `scanf` fails to recognize the second input.

Answer (score 5):

scanf tries to match the pattern you give it in the format string, and stops as soon as it fails to make a match.

```
scanf("%d/%d", &num1, &num2);
```

is trying to match a pattern consisting of 2 integers separated by a '/', so e.g. if you entered 12/22 num1 would be set to 12 and num2 would be set to 22.

If you only enter 12 then that will match the first %d in the format string, setting num1 to 12. num2 will not be touched. Since your code does not initialise num2 it could have any value; it happens that in your particular environment it's coming out as 32767; it could just as easily be 0 or 42 or any other value.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, num 2 is not initialized. That is why it's printing out garbage value. 
Try following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int num1, int num2;
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("%d", num2);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe to print something on the screen we use (the printf() function) to get some input from the keyboard we use (the scanf() function).Similar to the (cin function)in c++.